# get count of the ids in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I want to count all the entries against id

i have used this query

```
select count(*) from table1 group by `id`
```

the problem is my table has 3 records

```
id A   has 2 records
id B   has 1 record
```

when i run this query using php it gives me 2 enteries

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "db");

     $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tble1` GROUP by `ID`");

$query->execute();
$query->store_result();

$rowsaff = $query->num_rows;

echo $rowsaff;
```

Comment: And how many records do you actually expect here?  Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: *it gives me 2 entries*  It is correct as per your written query

Comment: i have three record 2 with same id actually it only counts one id

Comment: An id should be unique

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: id field is foriegn key index value

Comment: i have added a pic of my table structure and data

Comment: What is your expected  output ?

Comment: i want a result "entry number:3"

Comment: Count(distinct area)

Comment: area is actually numeric value and it could be same

Comment: i could not understand your problem what you want your query is correct it will return count of ids.Think again what you cant and explain correctly.

Comment: ok what do u thinks it returns?

Comment: it returns me number of entries :2

Comment: remove the group by id

Comment: Can you share the result you'd like to get?

Comment: Your problem simply seems to be that you are looking at the number of returned rows, whereas the value you are actually interested in is that of `COUNT(*)`. You need to go and fetch the content of that pseudo column, _not_ look at the number of rows returned. (That _has_ to be two, because the value you are GROUPing only has two distinct values.)

Comment: Never use * in SQL query. It will affect SQL query speed. Your server will get down on heavy load.

Comment: kindly tell me what to do

Comment: @CBroe sir kindly tell me what are u actually suggesting what iam doing wrong

Comment: Not even your question makes much sense so far … _“the problem is my table has 3 records”_ - how is that supposed to match the image you have shown? If you group that data as shown on the screenshot by id, then you would get a count of 6 for `a`, and 3 for `b`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: misunderstand the question.

You have to SELECT the count of the distinct id:

```
 $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(distinct `ID`) FROM `tble1`");
```

Comment: gives same result